# Eclipse Emacs command numeric argument

Tags: eclipse, emacs

Is there a way, with the Emacs bindings for the Eclipse editor, to specify a numeric argument for a command?  This is a very common thing to do in Emacs, usually for repetition.  Most implementations use Ctrl+u, but this doesn't work by default in Eclipse and I can't find any likely command that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Ctrl+u is not supported in the default Emacs bindings, but I found a plug-in that purports to offer it:

http://www.mulgasoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, Eclipse does not support prefix arguments to commands.